# Metrics for spatial datasets

Tags: geospatial

I'm working on a dataset of computer game replays. Each replay file describes the game of two players as a timeseries of game commands, where each command has a type and coordinates, like so: `(attack, 23.4, 75.1)` (simplified description).

I'd like to evaluate games based on the spatial information in the coordinates. For example, which player had broader command of the game map (e.g., area of the convex hull of their commands at different time points), which player had higher command density overall or in specific areas, etc.

I need something that summarises effectly across time and space. For example, if a player gave commands on all four corners of the map in one minute, then stayed in their little corner for the rest of the game, that's not as "powerful" as a player that effectively commanded the entire map area throughout the game.

I feel there must be a whole domain of pre-existing algorithms and metrics that should help me, but I'm not sure which keywords to search and read up on.

Does this problem sound like an obvious "oh, this is clearly a `foo` domain problem"? What is `foo`?